# What is the best way to get notification of notifications on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, notifications

I have been using the Stack suite for several years now and other than keeping a window open so that the little red notice is visible, I am yet to find a sane way to get notified when a response comes in. I have tried the RSS feed option, but they are not always timely and I find this one of the weakest aspects of Stack Exchange. Most forum systems use email notifications. So I am taking this to the Stack community to find out what the best options are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an Android phone or iPhone, download the Stack Exchange app for that system, keep its internet connection active, and make sure the notifications will produce a noise for you.

It'll pretty reliably give you a ping when you get a notification.

Comment: Does it simply connect with my Stack Exchange account?

Comment: Yes, you can log in and it's simple enough.

Comment: It might be nice to update this answer. AFAIK the Android App no longer exists.